# R: Fit custom n-th degree polynomial to each facet in facet_wrap'd ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a unique nth-degree polynomial fit to each facet in a facet-wrapped ggplot, but can't quite seem to get this to work.

One can use a uniform 1st degree linear fit for all facets with the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- diamonds

polys <- c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

custom.smooth <- function(formula, data,...) {
  smooth.call <- match.call()
  smooth.call[[1]] <- lm
  eval.parent(smooth.call)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x=carat, y=price)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~cut, scales='free') +
  stat_smooth(method='custom.smooth')
```

What I can't figure out is how to use the `ith` integer in `polys` as the polynomial degree for the `ith` facet in the plot.

Does anyone know how to achieve this behavior? Any help others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this what you want? `ggplot(df, aes(x=carat, y=price)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~cut, scales='free') +
  mapply(function(dat, i) 
  stat_smooth(data=dat, method='custom.smooth', formula=y~poly(x, i)),
     dat=split(df, df$cut), i=1:length(unique(df$cut)))`

Comment: @user20650 that doesn't seem to render anything in my RStudio -- is something missing?

Comment: duhaime, it renders in Rstudio & r terminal in  a fresh R session for me. ggplot v 3.0.0, R3.4.4

Comment: @user20650 I restarted RStudio yesterday and no love, but a system reboot today says, "yes", this is exactly what I was after! Can you please post an answer explaining why mapply gets the dat and i args here? If so I'll happily accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data to produce a separate smooth for each facet.

```
# set up
library(ggplot2)

df <- diamonds
custom.smooth <- function(formula, data,...) {
  smooth.call <- match.call()
  smooth.call[[1]] <- lm
  eval.parent(smooth.call)
}
```

Run function

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=carat, y=price)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~cut, scales='free') +
  mapply(function(dat, i) 
         stat_smooth(data=dat, method='custom.smooth', formula=y~poly(x, i)),
         dat=split(df, df$cut), i=1:length(unique(df$cut)))
```

To produce

[image]

---

`mapply` takes a function to apply over multiple arguments.  First a function is defined that takes two arguments:  1) data, 2) the polynomial degree.  This is no different from defining any other function

```
function(dat, i) stat_smooth(data=dat, 
                             method='custom.smooth', 
                             formula=y~poly(x, i))
```

The arguments are then defined  data: the raw data is partitioned into the data that is used in each facet,  and a vector of degrees, 1 to 5, is defined (this could be your `polys` vector)

```
split(df, df$cut)
1:length(unique(df$cut))
```

These arguments are then passed to `mapply`, via the dots argument, which runs the function over each set of parameters, to produce a named list of smooths that automagically are added to the facets.